# plot a curve as smaller parts, matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have a sequence of points i wish to plot, but the resultant curve could be broken at places if the points are too far apart.

**So in the 1D CASE :**

```
1 2 3 7 9 11 12  16 18 19
```

**Would be like :**

```
         1-2-3  7-9-11-12  16-18-19

or :      seq1     seq2      seq3
```

I want to plot my sequence as discrete parts `seq1` `seq2` and `seq3` which are not connected.

I am not too sure how to go about this

Comment: Intersperse your data with NaNs to get separate lines, lines will be of the same color though, e.g. `plot([1 2 3 NaN 7 9 11 12 NaN 16 18 19])`

Comment: How much difference is "too far"?

Comment: @Sardar_Usama , so that is problem specific, I guess you can use any distance metric of your choice and have a threshold value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sea the code snippet below for a solution of your problem. I tried to explain as much in the code as possible, but don't hesitate to ask, if anything is not clear.

```
% constants, thresold defintion
T = 4;
% your data
a = [1 2 3 7 9 11 12 16 18 19 24 25 26 28 35 37 38 39];

% preparing the x-axis
x = 1:length(a);

% Getting the differences between the values
d = diff(a);
% find the suggested "jumps/gaps", greater/equal than the threshold
ind = find(d>=T);

figure;
hold on;
% Plotting the first part of a
y = nan*ones(1,length(a));
y(1:ind(1)) = a(1:ind(1));
plot(x,y);

% Plotting all parts in between: go through all found gaps
% and plot the corresponding values of "a" between them
for j=2:length(ind)
    y = nan*ones(1,length(a));
    y(ind(j-1)+1:ind(j)) = a(ind(j-1)+1:ind(j));
    plot(x,y);
end;

% Plotting the last part of a
y = nan*ones(1,length(a));
y(ind(j)+1:end) = a(ind(j)+1:end);
plot(x,y);
```